# Undefined method `add_column_for_on_duplicate_key_update` - activerecord-import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-import

I'm trying to use activerecord-import as a way to import multiple records.

I'm trying to run

```
Field.import records, :on_duplicate_key_update => [:application_id,:key]
```

where `records` is an array of Field records.

The error I'm getting is:

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'add_column_for_on_duplicate_key_update' for # from /GEMS/gems/activerecord-import-1.0.4/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:1003:in 'block in add_special_rails_stamps'

I've also tried running `Field.import records`  and `Field.import records, on_duplicate_key_update: [:application_id, :key]` but both of them give the same error.

I've had a good search but I can't find anything of use anywhere else.

Comment: which rails version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

If You are Using Rails 6 then you can use:

```
Field.insert_all records
```

If not then try to use following syntax:

```
Field.import columns, [values]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm using Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate Key Update**(on_duplicate_key_update)

MySQL, PostgreSQL `(9.5+)`, and SQLite `(3.24.0+)` support on duplicate key update (also known as "upsert") which allows you to specify fields whose values should be updated if a primary or unique key constraint is violated.

Firstly check your version accordingly, for more reference read this https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import